# Possible bug: Wrong limit for `EllipticE`?

Tags: functions, special-functions

I encountered problem with computing limits of Elliptic functions E and F. For example,

```
EllipticE[ArcTan[ Sqrt[(2 p0)/(Bs^2 - 2 p0)]], (-Bs^2 + bv^2)/(
  bv^2 - 2 p0)] /. {bv -> 1, p0 -> 0.4, Bs -> 10000}
```

is evaluated to 0.000132281 whereas

```
EllipticE[ArcTan[Sqrt[(2 p0)/(Bs^2 - 2 p0)]], (-Bs^2 + bv^2)/(
  bv^2 - 2 p0)] /. {bv -> 1, p0 -> 0.4, Bs -> \[Infinity]}
```

yields `ComplexInfinity` instead of zero. Correct limit can be calculated using definition of `EllipticE` through the integral as follows:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 - m \[Theta]^2], {\[Theta], 0, \[Phi]}, 
 Assumptions -> {m < 0, \[Phi] > 0}]
% /. {m -> (-Bs^2 + bv^2)/(bv^2 - 2 p0), \[Phi] -> 
     ArcTan[Sqrt[(2 p0)/(Bs^2 - 2 p0)]]} // 
  Simplify[#, {bv^2 - 2 p0 > 0, p0 > 0, bv > 0}] &;
limE = Normal@
  Series[%, {Bs, \[Infinity], 1}, 
   Assumptions -> {bv^2 - 2 p0 > 0, p0 > 0, bv > 0}]
% /. {bv -> 1, p0 -> 0.4, Bs -> 10000}
```

This yields

> (Sqrt[bv^2 -    2 p0] ((Sqrt[2] bv Sqrt[p0])/(bv^2 - 2 p0) +
> ArcSinh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[p0/(bv^2 - 2 p0)]]))/(2 Bs)

and 0.000132281 as should be. Using directed limit still yields `ComplexInfinity`:

```
Limit[EllipticE[ArcTan[Sqrt[(2 p0)/(Bs^2 - 2 p0)]], (-Bs^2 + bv^2)/(
  bv^2 - 2 p0)], Bs -> Infinity, Direction -> Reals]
```

(* 0 *)

```
Limit[Bs*EllipticE[
   ArcTan[Sqrt[(2 p0)/(Bs^2 - 2 p0)]], (-Bs^2 + bv^2)/(bv^2 - 2 p0)], 
 Bs -> Infinity, Direction -> Reals, 
 Assumptions -> {p0 > 0, bv^2 - 2 p0 > 0, bv > 0}]
```

(* ComplexInfinity *)

But why?

Comment: Looks like a bug.